# More than one unique key in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `Product` table in my DB with following columns:

```
ProductId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
ProductCode VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
ProductStamp VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
```

ProductId is primary key. I need both ProductCode and ProductStamp unique separately (not combined). For example:

Allowed

```
    Code Stamp
... ---- -----
    A001 S001
    A002 S002
```

Not allowed

```
    Code Stamp
... ---- -----
    A001 S001
    A001 S002
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean unique together, or separately?

Comment: You can have UNIQUE constraint(s) in addition to PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: The alleged duplicate answer is not a duplicate after clarification by the asker. This post is about multiple keys, the duplicate target is about 1 key with mutiple columns.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Unique constraint on a single column:**

```
ALTER TABLE Product ADD CONSTRAINT AK_Product_ProductCode UNIQUE( ProductCode )
ALTER TABLE Product ADD CONSTRAINT AK_Product_ProductStamp UNIQUE( ProductStamp )
```

These will raise an error if there are two rows with duplicate product codes, OR product stamps.

**Unique constraint on a multiple columns:**

```
ALTER TABLE Product ADD CONSTRAINT AK_Product_ProductCodeAndStamp UNIQUE( ProductCode, ProductStamp )
```

This will fire if there are two rows with code AND stamp the same.

The convention "AK" for naming stands for "Alternate Key"

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a Unique Index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_NAME] ON [your_table] 
(
    ProductCode

) WITH IGNORE_DUP_KEY;
```

Comment: The question required ProductStamp to be considered, isn't?